# How to initailize a variable name with a dot notation in react JS?

Tags: reactjs, variable-names

The data which I'm getting from API is in this format having few keys in dot format and rest in normal. As javascript don't allow variable names having dot notation. How can I initialize variable names in dot notation ?

```
[{  
      "s.no":0,
      "amt.pledged":15823,
      "currency":"cad",
      "end.time":"2016-11-01T23:59:00-04:00",
}]
```

`

Comment: You can use `.` in your object property name if you use a string as property name, e.g. `var obj = {}; obj['wow.cool'] = 'test'; console.log(obj["wow.cool"]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const object = [{
  "s.no": 0,
  "amt.pledged": 15823,
  "currency": "cad",
  "end.time": "2016-11-01T23:59:00-04:00",
}];
console.log(object[0]["amt.pledged"]); // 15823

object[0]["amt.pledged"] = 1000;
console.log(object[0]["amt.pledged"]);  // 1000
```

or

```
const object = {
  "s.no": 0,
  "amt.pledged": 15823,
  "currency": "cad",
  "end.time": "2016-11-01T23:59:00-04:00",
};
console.log(object["amt.pledged"]); // 15823

object["amt.pledged"] = 1000;
console.log(object["amt.pledged"]); // 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below to create or initialize an object with keys containing .notation

```
    const obj = {};
    obj["s.no"] = 0;
    obj["amt.pledged"] = 15823;
    obj["currency"] = "cad";
    obj["end.time"] = "2016-11-01T23:59:00-04:00";
```

And while reading key values

```
   console.log(obj["amt.pledged"]);//this will print 15823
```